# Generate HTML table and load it in div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, getelementbyid

I'd like to load a HTML table into a div-element (id="resultDataDistancesTable") - but the generated string isn't processed (no matter if I use html(), append() or innerHTML). There is no error in the console.

When I paste the console.log(..) output directly to the HTML page I get the table that I want - so why doesn't my JavaScript code work? Is something wrong with the string?

```
var response = {"distances":[[0,4569,17264,6074,4986,12430,10936,11729,11280,23714,19112,24070,24974,25809,24157,27636,27323,15690,27970,22152],[4837,0,9160,1879,1872,12492,10755,15237,14468,21251,16649,17650,20574,23346,21694,31144,30831,13227,23141,19689],[17807,9681,0,8419,14314,25164,23427,28206,27140,11709,17204,18205,21130,23901,22249,30219,29906,4147,23696,10294],[6156,1736,8271,0,3191,12812,8437,16555,14788,22085,17483,18484,21408,24180,22528,30498,30185,14061,23975,20523],[5438,1642,14335,3147,0,12796,11058,15838,14771,20785,16183,17184,20108,22880,21228,31745,31432,12761,22674,19223],[12266,13371,25607,10970,13329,0,1842,20750,6094,32057,27455,28455,31380,34152,32500,37248,36935,24033,37581,30495],[10434,11651,16093,8428,11608,1842,0,19509,7092,30336,25734,26735,29659,32431,30779,35416,35104,22312,35750,28774],[12355,15633,28328,17138,16050,19963,20849,0,6457,34778,30176,26719,27624,33122,31702,30285,29973,26754,30619,33216],[11054,14433,26669,14776,14391,6088,9450,10828,0,33119,28517,36279,37184,35214,33562,39846,39533,25095,40179,31557],[21936,20085,11649,19803,18444,29293,27556,32335,31269,0,2943,8201,8702,10694,9042,17012,16699,8876,11268,5269],[19141,17291,16426,17009,15649,26499,24762,29541,28475,2924,0,5407,6515,9365,7713,15683,15370,14852,9082,6033],[22777,19065,18201,18783,17424,28274,26536,25758,31348,8188,5556,0,2979,5144,6115,10994,10681,16626,5493,10239],[23722,21760,20895,21478,20118,30968,29231,26703,32292,8634,6627,2994,0,2715,3388,4505,4192,19321,3110,11521],[29801,24947,24082,24665,23305,34155,32417,32782,38371,9673,8179,5136,2704,0,2345,4277,3964,22508,1703,15331],[25139,23289,22424,23007,21647,32497,30760,30797,34473,8016,6521,6129,3394,2340,0,5174,4862,20850,3779,13673],[26964,30242,30040,31748,30660,36952,35458,29945,35534,16511,10598,10365,4526,4274,5182,0,336,28466,1821,15492],[26628,29906,29704,31412,30324,36616,35122,29609,35198,16175,10262,10029,4190,3938,4846,313,0,28130,1485,15156],[16108,9772,4136,13975,12616,23466,21728,26507,25441,8931,10916,11916,14841,17613,15961,23930,23617,0,17407,7516],[27163,30441,23429,24012,22653,37151,35657,30144,35733,11168,9161,5495,3089,1703,3746,1686,1373,21855,0,14055],[22592,20741,10188,20459,19100,29949,28212,32991,31925,5369,5909,10225,11565,14414,12762,20732,20419,7415,14131,0]]};

buildResultTableDistances();

function buildResultTableDistances() {
    var tbl;
    var tr_head = "<table><tr><td>distances [meters]</td>";
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tr_head += "<td><b>" + "dummy" + "</b></td>";
    }
    tr_head += "</tr>";
    tbl = tr_head;

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var row = "<tr><td><b>" + "dummy" + "</b></td>";
        for (var ii = 0; ii < 20; ii++) {
            row += "<td>" + response.distances[i][ii] + "</td>";
        }
        row += "</tr>";
        tbl += row;
    }
    tbl += "</table>";
    console.log(tbl);
    $('#resultDataDistancesTable').html(tbl);
}
```

Comment: I've tried it myself and your code has worked fine - perhaps you've not got an element with the ID of "resultDataDistancesTable"? Also, is this being triggered after the page has finished loading or after the div (resultDataDistancesTable) has been created? If you try before-hand, it will fail.

Comment: stupid question, have you included a reference to jquery in your code? only asking because it wasn't included in your example.

Comment: @Nathangrad Your assumption was right (DOM wasn't loaded at that time).
@ Jared Includes are fine ;-) Erics answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you forgot to insert the HTML or including jQuery, because it works fine here.  If you want, to do this solely in JavaScript by adding the element in jQuery:

```
$(document.body).append('<div id="resultDataDistancesTable"></div>');
```

```js
var response = {"distances":[[0,4569,17264,6074,4986,12430,10936,11729,11280,23714,19112,24070,24974,25809,24157,27636,27323,15690,27970,22152],[4837,0,9160,1879,1872,12492,10755,15237,14468,21251,16649,17650,20574,23346,21694,31144,30831,13227,23141,19689],[17807,9681,0,8419,14314,25164,23427,28206,27140,11709,17204,18205,21130,23901,22249,30219,29906,4147,23696,10294],[6156,1736,8271,0,3191,12812,8437,16555,14788,22085,17483,18484,21408,24180,22528,30498,30185,14061,23975,20523],[5438,1642,14335,3147,0,12796,11058,15838,14771,20785,16183,17184,20108,22880,21228,31745,31432,12761,22674,19223],[12266,13371,25607,10970,13329,0,1842,20750,6094,32057,27455,28455,31380,34152,32500,37248,36935,24033,37581,30495],[10434,11651,16093,8428,11608,1842,0,19509,7092,30336,25734,26735,29659,32431,30779,35416,35104,22312,35750,28774],[12355,15633,28328,17138,16050,19963,20849,0,6457,34778,30176,26719,27624,33122,31702,30285,29973,26754,30619,33216],[11054,14433,26669,14776,14391,6088,9450,10828,0,33119,28517,36279,37184,35214,33562,39846,39533,25095,40179,31557],[21936,20085,11649,19803,18444,29293,27556,32335,31269,0,2943,8201,8702,10694,9042,17012,16699,8876,11268,5269],[19141,17291,16426,17009,15649,26499,24762,29541,28475,2924,0,5407,6515,9365,7713,15683,15370,14852,9082,6033],[22777,19065,18201,18783,17424,28274,26536,25758,31348,8188,5556,0,2979,5144,6115,10994,10681,16626,5493,10239],[23722,21760,20895,21478,20118,30968,29231,26703,32292,8634,6627,2994,0,2715,3388,4505,4192,19321,3110,11521],[29801,24947,24082,24665,23305,34155,32417,32782,38371,9673,8179,5136,2704,0,2345,4277,3964,22508,1703,15331],[25139,23289,22424,23007,21647,32497,30760,30797,34473,8016,6521,6129,3394,2340,0,5174,4862,20850,3779,13673],[26964,30242,30040,31748,30660,36952,35458,29945,35534,16511,10598,10365,4526,4274,5182,0,336,28466,1821,15492],[26628,29906,29704,31412,30324,36616,35122,29609,35198,16175,10262,10029,4190,3938,4846,313,0,28130,1485,15156],[16108,9772,4136,13975,12616,23466,21728,26507,25441,8931,10916,11916,14841,17613,15961,23930,23617,0,17407,7516],[27163,30441,23429,24012,22653,37151,35657,30144,35733,11168,9161,5495,3089,1703,3746,1686,1373,21855,0,14055],[22592,20741,10188,20459,19100,29949,28212,32991,31925,5369,5909,10225,11565,14414,12762,20732,20419,7415,14131,0]]};

buildResultTableDistances();

function buildResultTableDistances() {
    var tbl;
    var tr_head = "<table><tr><td>distances [meters]</td>";
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tr_head += "<td><b>" + "dummy" + "</b></td>";
    }
    tr_head += "</tr>";
    tbl = tr_head;

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var row = "<tr><td><b>" + "dummy" + "</b></td>";
        for (var ii = 0; ii < 20; ii++) {
            row += "<td>" + response.distances[i][ii] + "</td>";
        }
        row += "</tr>";
        tbl += row;
    }
    tbl += "</table>";
    $('#resultDataDistancesTable').html(tbl);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resultDataDistancesTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could replicate your issue using Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QxklTx0R6WcYwpRIpd98 has the fix. You weren't waiting for the DOM to be loaded before attempting to append to the object. See line 3:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  buildResultTableDistances();
});
```

Should work then.

Comment: Thank you Eric, this was helpful!! (seems like I cannot upvote yet because I have less than 15 reputations... sry!)

Comment: No problem, glad to help